# Import js file with TypeScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

## Abstract

I'm trying to import ".js" file from an external location (i.e. **node_modules**) I'm trying to do this using commonjs module pattern, however **import** wouldn't want to work with ".js" file types until I add ".d.ts" file near ".js" file in the same folder.

But the problem is that I wouldn't want to affect any **node_modules** with my ".d.ts" files. I want it to be located in another folder, separate from **node_modules** but as soon as I do that, typescript compiler throws an error:

## Example

I have the following folder structure:

```
|- DTS
|   |- y.d.ts
|- main.ts
|- y.js
```

**y.js** has the following content

```
module.export = function (x) {
    console.log(x);
};
```

**y.d.ts** has the following content

```
export interface Y {
    (x): any;
}
declare let y: Y;
export default y;
```

**main.ts** has the following content

```
import * as y from './y'
```

Now when I'm trying to compile **main.ts** with:

```
tsc -m commonjs -t ES2015 main.ts
```

I will get an error:

```
x.ts(1,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module './y'.
```

## Question

How to import ".js" files and being able to define it's ".d.ts" declarations while having both files located in different locations.

---

## Edit

[Here is the link to example project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51743054/tsc/tsc.zip). Be sure to use TypeScript version 2.0 compiler. And the `tsc` command above to see the error.

Comment: Have you tried including a line like the following at the top of main.ts? `/// <reference path="./DTS/y.d.ts" />`

Comment: I did but it does not help with failing `import` which works only when I put `d.ts` file into same directory. But I don't want to do that, because such action will affect external module which I download through `npm` so is there another way to be able both `import` js file and specify `d.ts` file when they are located in different folders?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note: The [official recommendation for proving your type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/README.md#test-a-new-package) takes a slightly different approach than what is presented below.
I believe the approach below is slightly better as the *.d.ts file is practically identical to the final product.

During typechecking (build time) TypeScript works with *.ts files and (mostly) **ignores *.js files**.
Let me offer an example that motivates what (I believe) you are proposing.
Suppose there exists a perfectly good JavaScript library that sadly has no typings (e.g. [N3](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/N3.js/)). 
Which has been installed via npm, thus:

```
npm install n3 --save
```

This, as is typical, is added to **./node_modules/n3/...** and project.json.
As mentioned the typings does not exist and needs to be added manually.
I create an **./@types/n3.d.ts** file for this purpose. 
For our purposes it is not particularly important what the definitions actually are but something like the following is a good start:

```
declare namespace N3 {
}

declare module "n3" {
    export = N3;
}
```

Now to your question.
Update the '**tsconfig.json**':

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "@types"
    ],
...
"paths": {
  "*": [
    ...
    "./@types/*"
  ]
```

It will still be necessary to deal with the run-time resolution for locating the corresponding *.js files but that is a different question than the one you asked.

For reference you may find [What is new in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) 
and [this discussion thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/213) useful.

This approach works fine when working with global variables but not so much with modules.

Update the '**tsconfig.json**':

```
...
"paths": {
  "*": [
    ...
    "./@types/*"
  ],
  "foo": [ "./@types/foo.d.ts" ]
  },
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> being able to define it's ".d.ts" declarations while having both files located in different locations.

`import` follows the same module resolution process when given a `.js` or `.d.ts` file with relative files.

Comment: It actually doesn't do that, I've edited the question and provided the example project where you can see the problem yourself...